# Spreadsheet with relationships

Tags: excel, spreadsheet, powerbi, powerquery, import-from-csv

I have to work with data CSV file. They look like this

[sample](https://www.dropbox.com/s/z2dueqewoco5mf5/sample.xlsx?dl=0)
It represents products with options/cars etc. at the web-store.

It has a lot of columns with duplicated values and in my work in often need to copy some part of this data to another sheet, deduplicate it, edit and then paste it back by matching it for one of the columns that were untouched. More this purpose I'm using Ablebits Excel suit.

Is it possible by any excel function to automate this process or maybe there is some other software that could handle this? Something not so complicated as relational databases like Access, but something close to spreadsheet editor with relationships

I already tried Power Query in Excel and Power Bi, but they seem to be more analytics tools and not the data edit

**2nd edition:** 
Data has a layer structure with duplicates.

```
Title1|Part number 1|Car1
Title1|Part number 1|Car2
Title2|Part number 2|Option1
Title2|Part number 3|Option2
```

I want to have opportunity to:

- Edit values that duplicate without using "Replace All" or at least have more flexible "Find&Replace".
- Extract columns with deduplicating them and saving a reference to the place they were taken. So if you edit some data there it was changed in the 1st place. For example, I have titles(a lot of titles) but need to edit it. Instead of copying it with some id to reference it I want to open it like they appears in filters, edit it, confirm and get it edited in all column

Comment: For us to answer this question, you need to be more specific. Please explain what part do you copy to another sheet, how do you deduplicate data, and what relation do you use to join it back. In short, using plain Excel formulas seem to be too complicated and ineffective, PowerQuery is much better tool for this task.

Comment: Also, please include (minimal) data for a repro *in the question*, don't expect us to go to an unknown dropbox link. See "[mcve]" for guidance.

Comment: You may use Google.Docs if you want to post table data, but any code should be posted here.

Comment: @Jeroen Although off-topic, your dishwasher experiment blew my mind away! :)) Great approach!

Comment: @eugene I respectfully disagree with your comment about Google Docs etc being okay: all info relevant and needed to answer should be in the question itself, as the Help Center clearly says. This is important for many reasons, including prevention of link rot, the fact that test data is essential in reliably answering, that it makes the question self-contained and more relevant to others with similar questions, that it requires OP to make the data minimal so that answering is easy and pleasant, etc. (PS. Glad you liked the dishwasher fish post :D)

Comment: @Jeroen Well, you're right about rotten links. The last question I answered contained Excel spreadsheet at Google Docs. It was quite convenient, since the example contained about 200 rows. I just have no idea how to place them all in question text well. This doesn't redeem  rotten link problem although.

Comment: @Eugene Either those 200 rows can be brought down by OP to a *minimal* example that more clearly demonstrates the issue and makes the question easier and more fun to answer, *or* the question is too specific to the data and will only be of use to OP, and is thus off-topic on SO. - I realize that creating minimal data for a [mcve] is hard work, but it's worth it if we want to get great questions.

Comment: PS. [I do try to practice what I preach](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A419956+%5Bpowerbi%5D+is%3Aq), if you're looking for examples.

Comment: I don't understand your definition of duplicates.  Each sample row you provided is unique.

Comment: @MikeHoney duplicates in columns(Title1 for example)

Answer (score 0):

I would use Power Query (aka Get & Transform on the Data ribbon in Excel 2016). The only limitation I see with what you want to do is that Power Query will deliver a new Excel Table with the output of a Query - it can't update existing cells.

If you can get past that, Power Query is very flexible, easy to learn (WYSIWYG query editor), scales well and is integrated with other Microsoft products (as well as Power BI, there is integration with SQL Server Analysis Services in preview and hopefully SQL Server Integration Services one day).

Comment: I'm using it to load CSV without autoformatting and combine few part of the same CSV to one file but still, I can't imagine how to work with data with it. Only way is to use that language in formals and write a script to it, but in this way, it's no difference use it or VBA